# Disable Dash searching for files

Tags: unity, unity-dash

I've looked fairly extensively, so I hope this isn't a duplicate.

I'm wondering how to disable the Dash search from searching for individual files; I am fine with searching for folders and applications, but searching for individual files in the dash can be obnoxious sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

Use Unity Tweak Tool: https://launchpad.net/unity-tweak-tool

Open using starter after installation, choose "Search", and disable all sources you do not want.

Answer (score 2):

Install [Unsettings](http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/unsettings/). Go to Dash tab and turn off Search all files.

Unfortunately Unsettings is not available in Software Center. You will have to add PPA.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:diesch/testing
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install unsettings
```

Full review on [OMGU](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/11/unsettings-a-comprehensive-tweaking-tool-for-unity).

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package unsettings` ... :-(

Comment: Nowadays [Unity Tweak Tool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-tweak-tool/_https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-tweak-tool/) should do the work.